# Is it possible to run a chef recipe without running the default recipe

Tags: ruby, admin, chef-infra

I have two chef recipes in my nginx cookbook. One is named default.rb and another named sites.rb. When I run the sites recipe with

```
RUN_LIST=recipe[nginx::sites] bundle exec cap staging chef:solo
```

then my default recipe is run as well. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: does your `sites.rb` include a `include_recipe "default"` line?

Comment: I have an `include_recipe "nginx"`. Not sure what recipe it refers to since I have no recipe file named nginx.

Comment: Recipe `nginx` is shorthand for recipe `nginx::default`, which is located in `$COOKBOOKS/nginx/recipes/default.rb`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove line

```
include_recipe "nginx"
```

because it includes default recipe (nginx::default)